# How can i create an input for choosing different files to access?

Tags: python, pandas

I am quite new to python so please bear with me.

Currently, this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import statistics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from datetime import datetime

start_time = datetime.now()


gf = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/aaronhuang/Documents/Desktop/ffp/exfileCLEAN2.csv",
                 skiprows=[1])
bf = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/aaronhuang/Documents/Desktop/ffp/2SeconddatasetCLEAN.csv",
                 skiprows=[1])

df = (input("Which data set? "))

magnitudes = (df['Magnitude '].values)
times = df['Time '].values
average = statistics.mean(magnitudes)
sd = statistics.stdev(magnitudes)
below = sd * 3


class data_set:
    def __init__(self, index):
        self.mags = []
        self.i = index
        self.mid_time = df['Time '][index]
        self.mid_mag = df['Magnitude '][index]
        self.times = []
        ran = 80
        for ii in range(ran):
            self.times.append(df['Time '][self.i + ii - ran / 2])
            self.mags.append(df['Magnitude '][self.i + ii - ran / 2])


data = []


today = float(input("What is the range? "))

i = 0
while (i < len(df['Magnitude '])):
    if (abs(df['Magnitude '][i]) <= (average - below)):
        # check if neighbours
        t = df['Time '][i]

        tt = True
        for d in range(len(data)):
            if abs(t - data[d].mid_time) <= today:
                # check if closer to center
                if df['Magnitude '][i] < data[d].mid_mag:
                    data[d] = data_set(i)
                    print("here")
                tt = False
                break
        if tt:
            data.append(data_set(i))
    i += 1
print("found values")

# graphing


height = 2  # Change this for number of columns
width = math.ceil(len(data) / height)
if width < 2:
    width = 2
fig, axes = plt.subplots(width, height, figsize=(30, 30))

row = 0
col = 0

for i in range(len(data)):

    axes[row][col].plot(data[i].times, data[i].mags)
    col += 1
    if col > height - 1:
        col = 0
        row += 1
plt.show()


end_time = datetime.now()
print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))
```

Currently, the error produced is this:

```
/Users/aaronhuang/.conda/envs/EXTTEst/bin/python "/Users/aaronhuang/PycharmProjects/EXTTEst/Code sandbox.py"
Which data set? gf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aaronhuang/PycharmProjects/EXTTEst/Code sandbox.py", line 14, in <module>
    magnitudes = int(df['Magnitude '].values)
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am trying to have the user be able to choose which file to access to perform the rest of the code on.

So if the user types `gf` I would like the code to access the first data file.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use an if-statement at the beginning? Try this:

instead of:

```
gf = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/aaronhuang/Documents/Desktop/ffp/exfileCLEAN2.csv",
                 skiprows=[1])
bf = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/aaronhuang/Documents/Desktop/ffp/2SeconddatasetCLEAN.csv",
                 skiprows=[1])

df = (input("Which data set? "))
```

Use this:

```
choice = input("Which data set? ")

if choice == "gf":
    df = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/aaronhuang/Documents/Desktop/ffp/exfileCLEAN2.csv",
                 skiprows=[1])
elif choice == "bf":
    df = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/aaronhuang/Documents/Desktop/ffp/2SeconddatasetCLEAN.csv",
                 skiprows=[1])
else:
    print("Error. Your choice is not valid")
    df = ""
    break
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't think of using an if statement.